# How do I format columns of a datatable using renderDataTable() in the DT package?

Tags: r, shiny, dt

I can format a column of a datatable object like so

```
library(DT)
datatable(data.frame(Amount=c(1.00, 2.20, 4.15))) %>% formatCurrency(columns='Amount')
```

[image]

But how can I do this using `renderDataTable()`?

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  DT::dataTableOutput('dtoMyTable')
))

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output){
  output$dtoMyTable <- DT::renderDataTable({
    data.frame(Amount=c(1.00, 2.20, 4.15))
  })
})

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: [Section 4.5](https://rstudio.github.io/DT/options.html)

Comment: @brittenb Note the last sentence "Since it is common for users to format numbers in the data columns, we have provided a few simple helper functions (e.g. formatCurrency()) in this package to do these tasks in a much easier way, so you do not have to write the JavaScript code by yourself." but no example of this is given.

Comment: `renderDataTable` takes a `DT::datatable` object, or an object that can be coerced to a `DT::datatable` object. So you simply need to wrap your `data.frame` call in the `server` side with `DT::datatable()` and then pipe that into `formatCurrency`.

Comment: Ah, thanks @brittenb

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Read the help page on `DT::renderDataTable`:

> renderDataTable(expr, ...
>
> expr
> an expression to create a table widget (normally via datatable()), or a data object to be passed to datatable() to create a table widget

So you just create the `datatable` object first, format as you wish, then call `renderDataTable`.

```
server <- shinyServer(function(input, output){
  dt <- datatable(data.frame(Amount=c(1.00, 2.20, 4.15))) %>% 
    formatCurrency(columns='Amount')
  output$dtoMyTable <- DT::renderDataTable({dt})
})
```

Comment: It works but produces a warning: `Warning in widgetFunc() :
  renderDataTable ignores ... arguments when expr yields a datatable object; see ?renderDataTable`.

Comment: @Konrad That means exactly what it means. You should put all extra parameters inside the `datatable()` call instead of outside. Like `DT::renderDataTable({datatable(dt, options = list(dom = 't', ordering = FALSE), rownames = FALSE)}`